# Pass string value created in one function as parameter to function

Tags: c#, reference, split

I have a function called ValidColumns that, when finished will contain a string of id values joined by the pipe character "|."

```
private bool ValidColumns(string[] curGlobalAttr, int LineCount)
{
    //test to see if there is more than 1 empty sku mod field in the imported file
    string SkuMod = GetValue(curGlobalAttr, (int)GlobalAttrCols.SKU);
    if(SkuMod =="") 
        ids += string.Join("|", OptionId);
 }
```

What I want to do is take the ids string and pass it as a reference into another function to check to see if it contains duplicate values:

```
protected bool CheckForDuplicates(ref string ids)
{
    bool NoDupes = true;
    string[] idSet = ids.Split('|');
    for (int i = 1; i <= idSet.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (idSet[i].ToString() == idSet[i - 1].ToString()) { NoDupes = false; }
    }
    return NoDupes;
}
```

But I am not sure how to do it properly? It seems so easy but I feel like I'm making this out to be much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Why are you try to pass it by reference, and what problems are you having with the code that you're using here?

Comment: Side note - you do not need to pass a reference since you aren't _changing_ the original string.

Comment: If I were you, I'd check for duplicates before doing the `Join` in the first function.  It saves the step where you have to re-split to check for dups.

Comment: I'm trying to return a true/false value form CheckForDuplicates based on whether the values stored in ids are duplicated. I.E. ids = 1676 | 1676 | 1676 | 1677 | 1678 | 1679. If this string, there are 3 instances of id 1676, and thus, CheckForDuplicates will return a value of false.

Comment: Why not use an enumerable collection instead of a pipe delimited string and then just use `Distinct`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx If you want a string at the end, you can `Join` your collection then.

Comment: Also note that you're not really checking for all duplicates - you're only checking for *adjacent* duplicates. Additionally, it's unclear why you're calling `ToString` on strings, or why you've got a `NoDupes` local variable at all when you could just return `false` immediately.

Comment: I would check before the join, but the ValidColumns function goes through an imported file line by line. If I include CheckForDuplicates inside it, then it will not work properly. I need to run CheckForDuplicates AFTER ValidColumns is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of D Stanley's answer is what you want

```
public bool CheckForDuplicates(string value)
{
  string[] split = value.Split('|');
  return split.Length != split.Distinct().ToArray().Length;
}
```

Comment: I like this idea but the problem still remains--how do I pass in the ids value from ValidColumns into this function? It is only after Valid Columns is completed that I will have all the values stored in the ids string....

Comment: @gallifrey1212 you pass in the valid ids from the string you build in your ValidColumns function.  You then in this method would check if the number of distinct items in the list are the same and the number of items in the list...  This appears to do everything you are requesting...

Answer (score 1):

```
if (idSet[i].ToString() == idSet[i - 1].ToString())
```

You're only checking each value against the *previous* value.  That would work if the values were sorted, but an easier method would just be to get a distinct list and check the lengths:

```
return (idSet.Length == idSet.Distinct().Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested loop to do this which will look at each item and compare it to another item.  This also will eliminate checking it against itself so it does not always return false.

In this we will track what we have already checked and only compare the new items against items after that slowly shrinking the second loop down in size to eliminate duplicate checks.

```
bool noDupes = true;

int currentItem = 0;
int counter = 0;

string[] idSet = ids.Split('|');

while(currentItem < idSet.Count)
{
    counter = currentItem + 1;

    while(counter < idSet.Count)
    {
        if(idSet[currentItem].ToUpper() == idSet[counter].ToUpper())
        {
            noDupes = false;
            return noDupes;
        }
        counter ++;
    }
    currentItem ++;
}

return noDupes;
```

Edit:

It was pointed out an option I posted as an answer would always return false so I removed that option and adjusted this option to be more robust and easier to step through logically.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Option 1 will always return false.

Comment: @MikeStockdale wow i feel stupid you are absolutely correct I will delete it from my answer... thanks for catching that...